# How to select fields in a non-uniform file using different delimiters?

Tags: awk, sed

I'm having trouble writing a one-liner that will select out the numbers between the parentheses, wrap it in double quotes, insert a comma, then select all the text after "USER_RULE: " up to the next double quote.

Here is a small sample of my file:

```
@213(1547485175) pass in quick on igb0 inet proto udp from <MGMT_HOSTS:1> to <UNRAID_IP:1> port = http keep state label "USER_RULE: Local Mgmt Services"
@174(1548683908) block return in quick on ALL_LAN inet proto tcp from <LOCAL_NETWORKS:7> to <LOCAL_BROADCAST:8> label "USER_RULE: Local Broadcast Noise"
@157(1547555119) block return in log quick on ALL_LAN inet from ! <NO_PFBLOCKER:1> to <pfB_BAD_IP_v4:55258> label "USER_RULE: pfb_Bad_IP (outbound)"
@137(1547478025) pass in quick on igb0 inet proto tcp from 192.168.1.0/24 to (self:13) port = ssh flags S/SA keep state label "USER_RULE: Anti-Lockout"
@386(1548774638) pass in quick on igb0.10 route-to (ovpnc1 10.20.48.141) inet proto udp from <MOBILE_DEVICES:5> to ! <PRIVATE_NETWORKS:3> port = https keep state label "USER_RULE: Policy Route" tag NO_WAN_EGRESS
```

Here's my expected output:

```
"1547485175",Local Mgmt Services
"1548683908",Local Broadcast Noise
"1547555119",pfb_Bad_IP (outbound)
"1547478025",Anti-Lockout
"1548774638",Policy Route
```

I've tried various combinations of awk, sed, and grep and I can get sort of the output I want. I just can't nail it. I'll spare you my ugly failed attempts.

Comment: If you spare us your "ugly failed attempts" then your question might just get multiple downvotes and closed since then you wouldn't have provided the minimum information needed to ask a question on this forum (see [ask]) so please - don't spare us :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ sed 's/[^(]*(\([^)]*\).*"USER_RULE: *\([^"]*\).*/"\1",\2/' file
"1547485175",Local Mgmt Services
"1548683908",Local Broadcast Noise
"1547555119",pfb_Bad_IP (outbound)
"1547478025",Anti-Lockout
"1548774638",Policy Route
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following(It is always recommended to add your effort in your post so kindly do so as we all are here to learn).

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  s1="\""
  OFS=","
}
match($0,/\([^\)]*/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)
}
match($0,/USER_RULE[^"]*/){
  print s1 val s1,substr($0,RSTART+11,RLENGTH-11)
}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
"1547485175",Local Mgmt Services
"1548683908",Local Broadcast Noise
"1547555119",pfb_Bad_IP (outbound)
"1547478025",Anti-Lockout
"1548774638",Policy Route
```

Comment: @Rick, could you please check this one too once and let me know?

Answer (score 0):

```
# File a.awk:

BEGIN { q = "\"" }
{ idx = index($0, "USER_RULE:")
  rule = substr($0, idx + 11)
  idx = index(rule, q) - 1
  print q substr($0, 6, 10) q "," substr(rule, 1, idx) 
}
```

Run:

```
$ awk -f a.awk file
"1547485175",Local Mgmt Services
"1548683908",Local Broadcast Noise
"1547555119",pfb_Bad_IP (outbound)
"1547478025",Anti-Lockout
"1548774638",Policy Route
```